# find one with multiple conditions mongoose mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to obtain data from mongodb. This is the scenario. Each user has a following property(array) that takes an array of users id.
The user model is as below

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  followers: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" }],
  following: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" }],
});
```

in simple terms. I need to use two conditions where postedBy: { $in: req.user.following }, or postedBy:req.user._id

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  photo: {
    type: String,

    required: true,
  },
  likes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "user" }],
  comments: [
    {
      text: String,
      postedBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" },
    },
  ],
  postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
  },
});
```

I have not figured out the second condition to add in the code below.

```
router.get("/getSubPost", requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await Post.find({
      postedBy: { $in: req.user.following },
    })
      .populate("postedBy", "-password")
      .populate("comments.postedBy", "_id name");
    res.json({ result });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: So what is it you are not getting in the result?

Comment: in simple terms. I need to use two conditions where  postedBy: { $in: req.user.following }, or postedBy:req.user._id